# ros-load:load-system doesn't load the package

Tags: ros, cram

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I run roslisp_repl and try the following command

(ros-load:load-system "cram_moveit" :cram-moveit)

The package is never loaded and the following warning is generates

System 'x-xml' is compiled by a different process. Waiting for compilation of blocking file to finish.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. This package used to load just fine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211355/ros-load:load-system-doesn%27t-load-the-package/) by [rohan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2278/rohan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 358 on 2015-06-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like if I delete .ros folder and then try loading the packages again it works.

---

Originally posted by [rohan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2278/rohan/) with karma: 358 on 2015-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/9301/gaya/) on 2015-06-15**:
Yes, you probably killed the building process before it could remove the lock which is stored in the `.ros` directory. You should "Mark as correct" the answers if they work for you, otherwise you flood the board with unanswered questions.